# the relationship between connection_pool_size and tp-processor?

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-jk

apache2 workers.properties:

```
worker.node223.connection_pool_size=100
worker.node223.connection_pool_minsize=50
```

tomcat server.xml:

```
<Connector address="192.168.0.17" port="8009" maxHttpHeaderSize="64836"
           maxThreads="350" minSpareThreads="50" maxSpareThreads="200"
           acceptCount="700" connectionTimeout="360000" disableUploadTimeout="true"
           enableLookups="false" URIEncoding="UTF-8" protocol="AJP/1.3" />
```

connection_pool_size should mean that max tcp connection numbers should be establish to backend server(tomcat).When I run kill -3 for tomcat server.as following:

```
........      
"TP-Processor499" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fb8455b5000 nid=0x4521 in Object.wait() [0x00007fb7ffe3f000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00007fb89017d430> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:662)
        - locked <0x00007fb89017d430> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)


"TP-Processor498" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fb8455b3000 nid=0x4520 runnable [0x00007fb7fff40000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:258)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317)
    - locked <0x00007fb8a486fde0> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.read(ChannelSocket.java:621)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.receive(ChannelSocket.java:559)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:686)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:891)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

........

then I get :

there are 295 TP-Processors, I guess 295< connection_pool_size+maxSpareThreads = 300； 295 < maxThreads = 350, it is ok.

there are 189 Tp-processors (In WAITING ) < maxSpareThreads  = 200, it is ok.

### there are 106 TP-Processors(In RUNNABLE ) > connection_pool_size = 100,I think it is wrong.

am I doing something wrong? And if not, do you know a possible explain to this?
thanks

Comment: in tomcat log ,I find: 
SEVERE: All threads (350) are currently busy, waiting. Increase maxThreads (350) or check the servlet status

for 350 >  connection_pool_size (100),so I think the log is unbelieveable。

I am confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If im reading you right, then 100 is the max threads per worker.  Perhaps there is more than one worker running.

```
http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/workers.html
```